# How do I ensure my email client (Thunderbird) is using Tor?

Tags: security, email

How do I direct my email client (Thunderbird) to use Tor when sending and receiving? Or am I not understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make sure it works properly is to use [TorBirdy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/torbirdy/)

> This extension configures Thunderbird to make connections over the Tor
>   anonymity network.

You should read the [wiki page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy) for it before you put it to use.